# Android AppCompat requires API level 11

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have an app that uses the `AppCompat` support libary for `ActionBars`. Now I tried to create a new themes.xml file with some style for that purpose.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

So just the same way it is done here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#StyleExample
However, Eclipse throws an error here and says:

```
android:actionBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 8) themes.xml
```

How can this be as I am using the support libary?

Comment: check my post and give it a try notice the changes and see if it works

Comment: Pity the Android developer docs are wrong.  Wastes a lot of time.

Comment: +1, Seriously, can't Android at least make the **tutorials** correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the below in `styles.xml` under `res/values-14`

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>
```

You would then need add the following into the values folder: `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

For more details

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Notice the change for API level 14+

```
 <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
```

To API level 7-13

```
 <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
```

Comment: Though I guess you mean `values-v14` as written in the link.

Comment: @user2433059 styles in res/values/styles.xml and res/values-14/styles.xml is what i meant

Comment: @user2433059 see the second part of the answer also. that is for api 7-13. Action Bar is available is 11 and so you use app compact support library below api level 11

Comment: for `red/values-v14` would you keep `AppCompat` or should you really swap it to `Holo`?

Comment: @xLite r u using actionbar below api 11 then follow the link in my post. that is all you need to do

Comment: @Raghunandan I know, Below 11 I use `AppCompat` but if it's 11+ is it good practice to change it to `Holo`, so it's `Theme.Holo.Light` for 11+ in `res/values-v11/styles.xml`??

Comment: @xLite if its 11+ no need to use appcompact at all

Comment: just tried it, turns out you *have* to use `AppCompat` as long as your `Activity` is extending `ActionBarActivity`.. damn