# cannot alter action bar background

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the background color of my action bar into a solid color but it just wont change. Here is the code that I have:
`/res/values/themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbarbg</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

`res/values/styles.xml`: (where the color is)

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<color name="actionbarbg">#8793FF</color>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

`/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fragment"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"        
android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity            
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.fragment.MainActivity" />
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

When I change the parent in `themes.xml`, it does apply it, i.e. if I change it to `AppCompat.Light`, however I do not know how to change the background color. I have looked around on the internet and Stack Overflow and none of the answers addressed my issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032138/android-appcompat-requires-api-level-11 solved the problem. /closed

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation - "You can control the behaviors and visibility of the action bar with the ActionBar APIs, which were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11)."

So, ActionBar will not work for your target environment which is at API level 10 (Android 2.3.3).

Just in case, if you target for minimum API level 11 , you can change ActionBar's background color by defining custom style, as:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

here **ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE**  you can use **#0000FF** for blue color as a example

And, set "MyTheme" as theme for application / activity.

```
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: The problem was that I needed to create one style.xml for api 14 and one for the default folder. Solved. Thanks for your help, though.