# Eclipse Android 2.2 project error but Android 4.0 no error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

When I create new project for lower android 2.2 label API8 in eclipse there are some error and i can't fixed them. `appcompat_v7` inside some problem no found `values-v17` - `values-v21` and there are also some error my project folder.

[image]

After creating ... ...

[image]

But when I create project for higher android 4.0 label API(14) there are no error.

[image]

After creating ... ...

[image]

There are any way to solve this problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your style.xml to ensure API's are supported. Please check this SO post [Android AppCompat requires API level 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032138/android-appcompat-requires-api-level-11)

This should help you solve the problem you face.

Answer (score 2):

In 4.0 they use android: prefix for styles but in 2.2 they does not recognise 
In 4.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

in 2.2

```
 <style name="WindowTitle">
        <item name="singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle</item>
        <item name="shadowColor">#BB000000</item>
        <item name="shadowRadius">2.75</item>
    </style>
```

like wise things changed. So refer the android [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com)
Or you can use separate stylesheet from 2.2 . And also without seen the style.xml we cant say that this is the exact problem.